# Many-to-many with Users and Groups and Items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I'm having trouble trying to understand/wrap my brain around this. I'm trying to create a relationship that allows this:

- User has_many Groups
- Item has_many Groups
- Groups has_many User
- Groups has_many Items

So I think I need a Join-Table here but belongs this table to three models or do I need two Join-Tables?

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :items
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

So what is the right migration here for my `Group` model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two separate many-to-many associations. Each many-to-many to many association requires a join table.

For `has_and_belongs_to_many` you can generate the migrations with:

```
$ rails g migration CreateJoinTableGroupsUsers group user
$ rails g migration CreateJoinTableGroupsItems group item
```

However `has_and_belongs_to_many` is very limited and `has_many through:` is usually a better option.

One example of the limits of `has_and_belongs_to_many` is that you can't add any additional columns on the join table (metadata) and you can't query the join table directly. So you're skrewed if you want to keep track of stuff like when a user joined a group or who added an item to a group.

```
$ rails g model Membership user:belongs_to group:belongs_to
$ rails g model GroupItem group:belongs_to item:belongs_to
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :group_items
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  has_many :items, through: :group_items
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_items
  has_many :groups, though: :group_items
end

class GroupItem  < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Comment: Yes my misstake

Comment: If I use ```User.last.groups``` I got this error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "memberships" does not exist)
LINE 8:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"memberships"'::regclass

Comment: Did you run the migrations?

Comment: oh man, sorry! I used a test system and forgot the migration after creating the join tables.